# htaccess and unicode (the letter 'נ')?

Tags: .htaccess, unicode, wamp, hebrew

I have an htaccess file which contains some rewriting rules, for friendly urls.
everything is working fine, except if I use the letter `'נ'` in hebrew.

Line (1) is working, line (2) isn't:

```
RewriteRule ^א$ file.ext
RewriteRule ^נ$ file.ext
```

I simply get a 500 error.

(I use wamp + win xp.pro)

Comment: Do you get the 500 error when you put the letter into .htaccess or into your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A browser like Firefox would encode such characters, usually using UTF-8. So the web server would receive "%D7%A0" in the URL instead of this character.

Try putting that into your .htaccess rule instead of the character itself:

```
RewriteRule ^%D7%90$ file.ext
RewriteRule ^%D7%A0$ file.ext
```

It could also be that your web application doesn't know how to handle UTF-8 encoded URLs and so gives you a 500 error message.

Comment: and other browsers will "understand" it?

Comment: @yossi it depends. Up until very recently there was simply no way _at all_ to have such letters in the URL. A couple of years ago (maybe even less) Firefox started to show such URLs in "decoded", human-readable form. You can test if your browser supports this by going to the Hebrew wikipedia and looking at the URL bar, to see if it has hebrew characters or stuff like %D7%A7%D7.

Comment: @romkyns: Don't look at the URL bar, look at the reality. The URL bar "beautifies" the URL. To get the real URL, go to the URL bar, select the whole URL and copy it into the clipboard. Then, paste it whereever you want, for example in a `notepad` window.

Comment: My point is that URLs still only consist of ASCII characters, no matter what Firefox displays in the "URL bar". (That comment didn't aim at you personally but at those readers who might think that URLs may contain arbitrary characters by now. I felt your comment suggested that.)

Comment: Thanks guys, however - the problem is not solved. for some reason these hebrew chars are rejected or ignored, and I need it solved since not all of my urls can be "translated".

Comment: @yossi this is still the correct answer. You need to look up which `%xy` sequence the character gets translated to. Then define the RewriteRule using *that*. The  unencoded `א` character has no business in the htaccess file

Comment: @Roland Indeed, my comment gives that impression, though hopefully not the answer. @yossi, I've added the two rewrite rules to my answer, see if this helps.